# Spring Security Kerberos, Kerberos + AD - Error: Access Denied, No key to store

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, kerberos, spring-security-kerberos

This is from Kerberos sample app found at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos/tree/master/spring-security-kerberos-samples/sec-server-win-auth corresponding to http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#samples-sec-server-win-auth.

All I’m doing is modifying the src/main/resources/application.yml to fit my system and going back and forth between creating SPNs and Keytab files.
My spring application seems to be starting fine. Below is the Kerberos config that comes through the console output.

> Debug is  true storeKey true **useTicketCache false useKeyTab true** doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator false **KeyTab is /etc/client-server.keytab** refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/client-server.example.org@REALM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
>   principal is HTTP/client-server.example.org@REALM
>   Will use keytab
>   Commit Succeeded

So I can see that the client app has accepted my settings so far. Then I try to access client-server:8080/hello through chrome on another machine. The first error I get is Acces is denied (user is anonymous). Which is supposed to redirect to the authentication entry point. Then I get the following, ending with “No key to store”

> [nio-8080-exec-4] w.a.SpnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter : Received Negotiate Header for request client-server:8080/favicon.ico: Negotiate YIIHZAYGKwYBBQUCoIIHWDCCB1SgMDAuBgk……./9AdsoFH2ya7C
>    [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.kerberos.authentication.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider
>    [nio-8080-exec-4] .a.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider : Try to validate Kerberos Token
>    [nio-8080-exec-4] .a.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider : **Succesfully validated myUsername@REALM**
>    [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.l.s.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch      : Searching for user 'myUsername@REALM', with user search [ searchFilter: '', searchBase: 'DC=xxxxx', scope: subtree, searchTimeLimit: 0, derefLinkFlag: false ]
>   Debug is  true storeKey true **useTicketCache true useKeyTab true** doNotPrompt true ticketCache is null isInitiator true **KeyTab is null** refreshKrb5Config is false principal is HTTP/client-server.example.org@REALM tryFirstPass is false useFirstPass is false storePass is false clearPass is false
>   Acquire TGT from Cache
>   Principal is HTTP/client-server.example.org@REALM
>   2015-11-27 11:38:47.906 DEBUG 3183 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
>   2015-11-27 11:38:47.906 DEBUG 3183 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
>   2015-11-27 11:38:47.912 ERROR 3183 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: No key to store; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: No key to store [Root exception is javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store]

Now it appears that the app is able to validate my user, but I have no idea if it could find my user info.
Viewing the source for Krb5LoginModule.java at cr.openjdk.java.net/~weijun/7201053/webrev.00/raw_files/new/src/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.java, you can find the login exception, no key to store, by simple search. The code says that my ktab (keytab I’m guessing), is null. Strangely enough, the console output does say that when I try to navigate using the browser, that the keytab is null, even though it wasn’t when I started up the application.

Does anyone know why my keytab is going null when I have a user try to access my application? Or is something else wrong with my application or system configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I slept on this for the weekend. Strangely enough, it looked like the solution now works since the TGT acquired from cache was past renewal time. I don’t really know how it all works, but now the keytab is accepted when my user navigates to the application.
The only problem left was the Ldap couldn’t find my user details due to a mismatch between the Kerberos username used to query LDAP, so I had to re-implement org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch to modify the username. Then the solution worked.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue, and the root cause was actually a corrupt key created by kinit.  The solution was to delete the cache (both under /tmp/kbr5cc_[UID], and in the value set by        ticketCache="/home/solr/cache" in the JAAS config file, and NOT to run kinit before starting the app.

To find what was going on, I added the following flag to the JVM: -Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true

I saw that the key had the start and end time set to the epoch date:

```
>>>DEBUG <CCacheInputStream> key type: 0
>>>DEBUG <CCacheInputStream> auth time: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
>>>DEBUG <CCacheInputStream> start time: null
>>>DEBUG <CCacheInputStream> end time: Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 1970
>>>DEBUG <CCacheInputStream> renew_till time: null
```

Comment: Same in my case. Once I removed cache file as @Leo mentioned above, this weird exception "No key to store" has gone and keytab started to be used successfully.